# nested custom FormArray component doesn't bind with child form with FormArrayName

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I tried to have 2 nested forms using CVA. the problem is the second from isn't initialized with data when I bind it to a formControl.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zny8fj)

[image]

I have **MAIN-FORM**:

```
this.requestForm = this.fb.group({
  garageId: 0,
  routes: new FormArray([
    new FormGroup({
      addressPointId: new FormControl,
      municipalityId: new FormControl,
      regionId: new FormControl,
      rvId: new FormControl,
      sequenceNumber: new FormControl,
      settlementId: new FormControl,
      regionName: new FormControl,
      municipalityName: new FormControl,
      settlementName: new FormControl,
      description: new FormControl,
    })
  ]),
  endDateTime: 0,
});
```

In main-form html I bind routes to  with formArrayName.

```
 <app-cva-form-array formArrayName="routes"></app-cva-form-array>
```

Component **CVA-FORM-ARRAY** has.

```
form = new FormArray([
new FormGroup({
  addressPointId: new FormControl,
  municipalityId: new FormControl,
  regionId: new FormControl,
  rvId: new FormControl,
  sequenceNumber: new FormControl,
  settlementId: new FormControl,
  regionName: new FormControl,
  municipalityName: new FormControl,
  settlementName: new FormControl,
  description: new FormControl,
})
]);
```

Everything from here works just fine. I bind each formGroup in the array to child component CVA-FORM.

```
<app-cva-form [formControl]="route" (blur)="onTouched()"></app-cva-form>
```

**CVA-FORM**
for each formGroup I created separate component in case I want to use component itself not the whole array.

```
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    regionName: new FormControl,
    regionId: new FormControl,
    municipalityName: new FormControl,
    municipalityId: new FormControl,
    sequenceNumber: new FormControl,
    settlementName: new FormControl,
    settlementId: new FormControl,
    addressPointId: new FormControl,
    description: new FormControl,
    rvId: new FormControl,
  });
```

the main-form <--to--> app-cva-form-array binding doesn't work for some reason.

The idea of these forms comes from [kara's talk on angulaconnect.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CD_t3m2WMM8&t=2289s) 
[here are her slides.](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTS20UdnMGqA3ecrv7ww_7CDKQM8VgdH2tbHl94aXgEsYQ2cyjq62ydU3e3ZF_BaQ64kMyQa0INe2oI/pub?slide=id.g293d7d2b9d_1_1585)

help plz!

Comment: Not clear to me are you asking about background form?

Comment: yes. if you look at jsons. you will see that the main-form (background form) is out of sync with others.

Comment: Have a look at posetd answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use "custom Form Control", you need take account that you feed the cursom Form Control with a Form Control (not FormArray, not FormGroup). The FormControl has as value an array or an object, but you need not confussed about this.(*)

You can see in work in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mj1u63?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmain-form%2Fmain-form.component.ts)

That's your form is like

```
//in main.form
this.requestForm = new FormGroup({
  garageId: new FormControl(0),
  routes: new FormControl(routes), //<--routes will be an array of object
  endDateTime: new FormControl(0)
})

//in cva-form-array
this.form=new FormArray([new FormControl(...)]); //<-this.form is a 
                             //formArray of FormControls NOT of formGroup

//finally in your cva-form
this.form=new FormGroup({});
this.form=formGroup({
      addressPointId: new FormControl(),
      municipalityId: new FormControl(),
      ...
})
```

I've create a const to export to simply the code. MY const expor is

```
export const dataI = {
  addressPointId: "",
  municipalityId: "",
  regionId: "",
  rvId: "",
  sequenceNumber: "",
  settlementId: "",
  regionName: "",
  municipalityName: "",
  settlementName: "",
  description: "",
}
```

So, in mainForm we have

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let routes:any[]=[];
    routes.push({...dataI});
    this.requestForm = new FormGroup({
      garageId: new FormControl(0),
      routes: new FormControl(routes),
      endDateTime: new FormControl(0)
    })
  }
<mat-card [formGroup]="requestForm" style="background: #8E8D8A">
    <app-cva-form-array formControlName="routes"></app-cva-form-array>
</mat-card>
```

In cvc-form array create the formArray when we give value

```
  writeValue(v: any) {
    this.form=new FormArray([]);
    for (let value of v)
        this.form.push(new FormControl(value))

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>
    {
      if (this.onChange)
        this.onChange(this.form.value)
    })
  }

    <form [formGroup]="form" >
        <mat-card *ngFor="let route of form.controls; 
            let routeIndex = index; let routeLast = last;">
           <button (click)="deleteRoute(routeIndex)">
             cancel
           </button>
           <app-cva-form [formControl]="route" (blur)="onTouched()"></app-cva-form>
      </form>
```

Finally, the cva-form

```
  writeValue(v: any) {
    this.form=new FormGroup({});
    Object.keys(dataI).forEach(x=>{
      this.form.addControl(x,new FormControl())
    })

    this.form.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false });
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(res=>{
       if (this.onChanged)
        this.onChanged(this.form.value)
    })
  }

<div [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field class="locationDate">
    <input formControlName="regionName">
    <mat-autocomplete #region="matAutocomplete" 
      (optionSelected)="selectedLocation($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let region of regions" 
      [value]="region">
        {{region.regionName}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="locationDate">
    <input formControlName="municipalityName" 
      [matAutocomplete]="municipality"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
      [readonly]="checked || this.form.value.regionId < 1">
   ....
   </form>
```

(*) Yes, we are used to seeing that a FormControl has as a value a string or a number, but no one forbids us that the value is an object or an array (for example, ng-bootstrap DatePicker stores an object {year: .. month: .., day ..}, mat-multiselect stores an array, ...)

**Update** Of course we can feed our control with data from a service or similar. The only thing we must take account is how we give the data. As usually I like make a function that received a data or null and return a FormControl

```
  getForm(data: any): FormGroup {
    data = data || {} as IData;
    return new FormGroup({
      garageId: new FormControl(data.garageId),
      routes: new FormControl(data.routes),
      endDateTime: new FormControl(data.endDateTime)
    })
  }
```

where IData is an interface

```
export interface IData {
  garageId: number;
  routes: IDetail[];
  endDateTime: any
}
```

and IDetail another interface

```
export interface IDetail {
  addressPointId: string;
  ...
  description: string;
}
```

Then we can have a complex data like (sorry for the large object)

```
let data = {
  garageId: 1,
  routes: [{
    addressPointId: "adress",
    municipalityId: "municipallyty",
    regionId: "regionId",
    rvId: "rvId",
    sequenceNumber: "sequenceNumber",
    settlementId: "settlementId",
    regionName: "regionName",
    municipalityName: "municipalityName",
    settlementName: "settlementName",
    description: "description",
  },
  {
    addressPointId: "another adress",
    municipalityId: "another municipallyty",
    regionId: "another regionId",
    rvId: "another rvId",
    sequenceNumber: "another sequenceNumber",
    settlementId: "another settlementId",
    regionName: "another regionName",
    municipalityName: "another municipalityName",
    settlementName: "another settlementName",
    description: "another description",
  }],
  endDateTime: new Date()
}
```

Then only need make

```
this.requestForm = this.getForm(data);
```

The stackblitz if updated

Comment: Thanks for the answer! can I use Interface instead of the const? I don't want the form-array to be bound to main form. Or do you think I should have the const in different file?

Comment: hello, I tried to put the solution in my project. I try to load initial data that already exists. I followed the same code as yours. but I noticed when I initialize with data it doesn't transfer to children and when I try to add another routes it puts index in front of array objects. like this "routes": { "0": { "regionId": "" ... "municipalityId": "" } }.  this might be the problem with initialization too. do you know what might be the solution?

Comment: @Vato, I updated the answer and the stackblitz, I hope this help. About use an Interface nor a const, I tryed, but with no result :(, but of course the interfaces and the constans can be outside the main-form

Comment: @Eliseo, thanks it works great. but it still adds index in front of arrays once you add address. it makes arrays { 0: {} 1: {} ... } etc. before you add the array looks fine [{ },{ },{ }]

Comment: nevermind. I removed {... } spread from onChange and it adds to array without indexes. I am not yet familiar with spread, so it confused me. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'm happy you find the "bug"

Comment: Thinking about the problem, really you can remove at all the this.onChange, in the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6seas7?file=src/app/cva-form-array/cva-form-array.component.ts (forket stackblitz) I remove and look like work

Comment: @Eliseo for some reason, I still can't preload data from service. I get each route from server and I push them to routes.push({...route}), but when the data gets to cva-form-array it dousn't go through writeValue loop where you add them to the form. I've noticed it doesn't go in  for (const value of v) loop. In first case where I add dataI, I print the v in writeValue and I get [{...}] in console, but when I write new data from server over dataI, In writeValue it prints []. Both array's consist of same type of objects once I expand them in browser tools but first is just empty values ' '.

Comment: what is the difference between [] and [{...}] and how could it affect for (const value of v) loop? Sorry for bothering again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722761/vs-in-browser-tools-while-both-having-same-objects I posted another question about what I wrote in top. I include my service call in there.

Comment: to avoid the problem I had with the brackets (not loading files in time). I called the service in the parent component that calls the main form in dialog. So I passed the dialog already ready data. this way the forms are filled now. I am not sure if there is a better way or time to call my service, but this works fine by far :)

Comment: the only thing is now I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. which is not too bad. I'll try to solve this.

Comment: to avoid ExpressionChanged... it's util sometimes use `setTimeOut(()=>{...your code..})`

Comment: I guess nested FormControls/FormGroups validation state cannot be reflected on the top level Form when using this method. Am I wrong ?
It would be great to propagate the validation state of app-cva-form controls to the main form.

Comment: How to binding FormArry to [formGroup] directive? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30264#issue-440372324

Comment: @qslcna, Since Angular 9 (I think remember) you can not. You can take another aproach:https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/30264#issuecomment-1069282213

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that `formArrayName` is not an input for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR/DefaultValueAccessor`.

**Also note:**

> Her examples are static `parent->multiple children`... meaning 1 to many and not dynamic. You are attempting static
>   `parent` to many dynamic `child->grandChild` relationships built from `formArray`, then trying to dynamically link `grandChild` form to parent `formArrayIndex` that was passed through the `child` to the `grandChild`. Your stackblitz deviates from the structure she is teaching, and certainly introduces some new challenges not covered in the lecture.

Exploring how to iterate over the `FormArray` at the `parent` level and instantiate your `child->grandchild` relationship from within that loop may be a possible solution, this way you are not passing the entire array down, only the `formGroup` that would apply.

```
<h1>MAIN FORM</h1>
    {{ requestForm.value | json }}
    <div *ngFor="let route of requestForm.get('routes').controls">
        <app-cva-form-array formControl="route" (onChildFormValueChange)="onFormChange($event)"></app-cva-form-array>
    </div>
```

---

Selectors

- **input**:not([type=checkbox])**[formControlName]**
- **textarea[formControlName]**
- **input**:not([type=checkbox])**[formControl]**
- **textarea[formControl]**
- **input**:not([type=checkbox])**[ngModel]**
- **textarea[ngModel]**
- **[ngDefaultControl]**

https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor#selectors

---

Your only options for input are `formControlName`,`formControl`, `ngModel` and `ngDefaultControl`...

> This is the reason `formArrayName` will **not** work in `main-form
>   <--> cva-form-array` however, `formControl` **will** work for
>   `child-child to child level`, as you are passing a singular
>   `formControl` into your `app-cva-form`, from your `app-cva-form-array`
>   via the `*ngFor` loop.

```
<mat-card *ngFor="let route of getForm.controls;
   <app-cva-form [formControl]="route" (blur)="onTouched()"></app-cva-form>
```

---

I believe the key to understand here is that `formArray` is only an organizational container for its children... it will not do what you are wanting it to in this scenario without help from additional logic.

> There currently doesn't appear to be the necessary functionality to
>   accept `formArray` as an input, iterate/dynamically manage the array,
>   and link changes back to the parent `formArray`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the updated form data from Child Component to Parent Component. I have used `this.form.valueChanges()` method to detect the changes and then emit the Form value to the parent component.

> Parent Component:

HTML Code:

```
<app-cva-form-array formArrayName="routes" (onChildFormValueChange)="onFormChange($event)"></app-cva-form-array>
```

TS Code:

```
public onFormChange(form): void {
    this.requestForm = form;
}
```

> Child Component:

HTML Code:

```
No change:)
```

TS Code:

```
@Output() onChildFormValueChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

registerEvent() {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.onFormValueChange()
    });
}

public onFormValueChange(): void {
    this.onChildFormValueChange.emit(this.form);
}
```

and call `registerEvent` method in the constructor like:

```
constructor(){
  this.registerEvent();
}
```

[`Working_Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-doj7pq)

Comment: this gives only one way binding. although I know how to do 2 way, Its still not what I'm looking for. if you check how cva-form-array binds to cva-form, I want to achieve similar binding for main-form <--> cva-form-array. the goal of using cva is to simplify code and not use extra functions.

Comment: I added external resources about the origin of code at the bottom of question.

Comment: @Vato Nope it's two-way binding

Comment: If you change the main-form the cva-form-array isn't changing. if you write  regionName: new FormControl('asdfa'), in main-form it leaves children component regionnames null.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b6nm8c here if you add array from parent it isn't bount to child only vice versa. but anyways, as I said none of the functions should be required using cva.